# Windows 8 metro - errors while navigating between pages in C#

Tags: c#, windows, button, microsoft-metro

on a MainPage, I have a button which could take me to another page.

```
private void button_clicked(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (this.Frame != null)
     {
          this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AnotherPage));
     }
}
```

However, it gives me this error:

Error   1   'test.CreateAccountPage' does not contain a definition for 'button_createAccount_clicked' and no extension method 'button_createAccount_clicked' accepting a first argument of type 'test.CreateAccountPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Anggrian\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test\test\CreateAccountPage.xaml    55  98

I swear to God it worked yesterday, now I am clueless

Comment: Try changing the method name to `button_createAccount_clicked`, then use the refactoring controls to change it to what you want it to be.  Otherwise look through your XAML and replace `button_createAccount_clicked` with `button_clicked`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to line 55 in C:\Users\Anggrian\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test\test\CreateAccountPage.xaml and replace `button_createAccount_clicked` with `button_clicked`